# MySQL loops without stored routine

Tags: mysql, loops, batch-processing

I often find myself needing to perform batch-like MySQL operations. Now I need to call a stored routine 1,000 times with the argument 0, 1, 2, ... 1,000. I could create a stored routine with a `LOOP` construct to do this, or write

```
CALL MyStoredRoutine(0);
CALL MyStoredRoutine(1);
...
CALL MyStoredRoutine(1000);
```

Both of these options are pretty cumbersome I think. I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the requirement is to just pass in a single INT parameter, you can use a bash one-liner in the shell if you are using *nix (with mysql user credentials supplied by ~/.mylogin.cnf).

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do mysql -e "call `db`.`selecta`($i)"; done

+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
...
```

Here, procedure `selecta` is just doing a SELECT on the parameter passed to the procedure but you could apply the technique to any routine.